# Blazor Server App - 404 Not Found in MS Edge when streaming using WebRTC

Tags: iis, blazor, webrtc, microsoft-edge, blazor-server-side

I'm building a Blazor Server app, that includes a screen sharing element using WebRTC. It works fine in both Chrome and Firefox, but I keep getting a 404 error in MS Edge. It starts streaming, then goes grey with the 'Could not reconnect to server' error, it's still streaming behind the grey screen.
I've attached the error I get, any one have any idea what's causing this? Or how I can fix it?
Also, the server is an IIS server.

[image]

Comment: Do you see any error/crashes in the dev console?

Comment: Console shows 'Failed to load resource' for the element in the network tab, and then 'Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: No Connection with that ID: Status code'404''

Comment: I was also getting a warning about web socket not connecting. I've installed web sockets on the server, and now I get the following error in the console 'Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Websocket closed with status code: 1006 (no reason given)''

Comment: The websocket 1006 error means that the connection has been closed, locally, by your browser. If you see a close code 1006, you have a very low level error with WebSocket itself as this error is not really meant for the user. The websocket 1006 error points to a low level issue with your code and implementation, maybe you should check the websocket.onerror(evt) event for details.

Comment: Try using FRT to view details about the 404 error, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis